# Adding texture to plot based on a condition in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

From the following `dataframe` df:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=1:5,
                Cat1=c(1,0,1,0,0),
                Cat2=c(1,1,1,0,0),
                Cat3=c(0,1,1,0,1),
                Cat4=c(0,0,1,1,0),
                Mask=c(0,1,1,0,0))

df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -1)
```

A tile plot is plotted as follows:

```
ggplot(df%>%filter(name!="Mask"),
       aes(x = Date, y = factor(name, levels = rev(unique(name))), 
           fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "grey50")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

with the following output:

[image]

In `ggplot`, How it is possible to implement a texture by using the column `Mask==1` in order to fill the `Date`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the (not on CRAN) `ggpattern`-package

```
library(ggplot2)
#remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)
# set what cells need to be hatched
df <- df %>%
  mutate(hatch = ifelse(Date %in% c(2,3), "yes", "no"))
  
ggplot(df%>%filter(name!="Mask"),
       aes(x = Date, y = factor(name, levels = rev(unique(name))), 
           fill = as.factor(value), pattern = hatch)) +
  geom_tile_pattern(pattern_color = "black",
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.1,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.5) +
  geom_tile(color = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(yes = "stripe", no = "none")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "grey50")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

[image]